# Are "=>" Expressions Called Right Away?

Tags: c#, razor, expression

I have numerous lists of type `List<SelectListItem>` in my model that are set using the `=>` Expression like so:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users => Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
```

I was under the impression that these were called when the class was created so I moved them into a `LoadLists` methods so that I could call the specific method when needed for efficiency.

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users {get;set;}

public void LoadLists()
{
   this.Users = Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
}
```

This caused an issue on my views as the `Users` select list was being used in multiple `DropdownListFors` that caused any nullable `DropdownListFor` to hold the most recent value that was using the `Users` select list.

When using the original `public List<SelectListItem> Users => Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();` this issue didnt occur as Im assuming it was called each time the `Users` select list was being used on the view?

So I created a dummy `List<SelectListItem>` like:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Test => Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
```

and didn't use it on the view and the debug line was never hit. So my question is is `=>` Expressions only executed when they are used somewhere?

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar - under the hood, it's exactly like you wrote the method longhand.

Comment: "I was under the impression that these were called when the class was created" Then your impression is whrong. `=>` in this context is just a simplification for a normal `public List<SelectListItem> Users get { return Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList(); }` which is executed when you access that property.

Comment: Say I had 3 DropdownListFors that used the User list. For each of the 3 DropdownListFors the debugger goes an hits that expression which means the select lists are their own. When I put it in the method its only called once so each DropdownListFor has reference to the same user list which maintains the Selected value.

Comment: "So my question is is => Expressions only executed when they are used somewhere?" Why not just try it out by putting a breakpoint and see, when it´s hit?

Comment: I did. I said what I found in my above comment and in the OP with the Test select list. So I'm assuming its only ever called when the property is access and can be called multiple times depending on how many times the property is reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users => Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
```

defines a **property** with only a `get` accessor. It means exactly the same as this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users
{
    get { return Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList(); }
}
```

The `=>` notation was introduced as a syntax alternative for doing the same with fewer lines of code.

And to answer your question: yes, every time `Users` is called, the property body executes, for both notation variants.

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users => Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
```

Is just syntactic sugar for:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Users { 
    get { 
        return Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
    }
}
```

It is called an [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Comment: "So my question is is => Expressions only executed when they are used somewhere?"

Comment: So its only called if the property is accessed?

Comment: Yes, Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList(); is called when the property is accessed.

Comment: @BadDub Yes. And note: It is called **each time** the Property is accessed. So you'll have a different list ( instance ) every time.

Answer (score 3):

`=>` can mean different things in different context. In this scenario, it simply denotes a way of describing a property getter. Property getters are not invoked "immediately" - rather, they are invoked only when the property is accessed, and *every* time the property is accessed.

The "immediate" version (at object initialization time) would be:

```cs
public List<SelectListItem> Users {get;} = Service.GetAll<User>().ToSelectList();
```

which is an automatically implemented property backed by a field with a field-initializer that is run before the type's constructor.